# can't install wsgi_mod-3.3 for django on ubuntu

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu

I am trying to get my web server running on Ubuntu using Apache2 in order to run my site built with Django. Following the [official django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/), I successfully got the apache server to run the django app. However, I am using Python 3.3, and when I installed mod_wsgi, it was configured for the wrong python version, so the app gets a 500 internal server error and the Apache error logs show `ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi`.

I am attempting to install mod_wsgi built for Python 3.3 with the following terminal commands.

```
mkdir ~/sources
cd ~/sources
wget http://modwsgi.googlecode.com/files/mod_wsgi-3.3.tar.gz 
tar xvfz mod_wsgi-3.3.tar.gz
cd mod_wsgi-3.3
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

However, when I get to `make` I get an error and I am unable to continue.

```
~/sources/mod_wsgi-3.3$ make
/usr/bin/apxs2 -c -I/usr/include/python2.7 -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   mod_wsgi.c -    L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config  -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm
/usr/share/apr-1.0/build/libtool --silent --mode=compile --tag=disable-static x86_64-    linux-gnu-gcc -std=gnu99 -prefer-pic -pipe -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4     -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-aliasing  -    D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE  -pthread  -I/usr/include/apache2  -    I/usr/include/apr-1.0   -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -    DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -c -o mod_wsgi.lo mod_wsgi.c && touch mod_wsgi.slo
mod_wsgi.c: In function 'wsgi_process_socket':
mod_wsgi.c:10095:37: error: 'conn_rec' has no member named 'remote_addr'
 if ((rv = apr_socket_addr_get(&c->remote_addr, APR_REMOTE, sock))
                                 ^
mod_wsgi.c:10103:27: error: 'conn_rec' has no member named 'remote_ip'
 apr_sockaddr_ip_get(&c->remote_ip, c->remote_addr);
                       ^
mod_wsgi.c:10103:41: error: 'conn_rec' has no member named 'remote_addr'
 apr_sockaddr_ip_get(&c->remote_ip, c->remote_addr);
                                     ^
mod_wsgi.c: In function 'wsgi_hook_daemon_handler':
mod_wsgi.c:12742:18: error: 'conn_rec' has no member named 'remote_ip'
 r->connection->remote_ip = (char *)apr_table_get(r->subprocess_env,
              ^
mod_wsgi.c: In function 'Auth_environ':
mod_wsgi.c:13262:10: error: 'conn_rec' has no member named 'remote_ip'
 if (c->remote_ip) {
      ^
mod_wsgi.c:13263:18: error: 'conn_rec' has no member named 'remote_ip'
     value = c->remote_ip;
              ^
mod_wsgi.c:13295:14: error: 'conn_rec' has no member named 'remote_addr'
 rport = c->remote_addr->port;
          ^
mod_wsgi.c: In function 'wsgi_hook_access_checker':
mod_wsgi.c:14395:29: error: 'conn_rec' has no member named 'remote_ip'
     host = r->connection->remote_ip;
                         ^
mod_wsgi.c: At top level:
mod_wsgi.c:14697:5: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
 &wsgi_check_authorization,
 ^
mod_wsgi.c:14697:5: warning: (near initialization for     'wsgi_authz_provider.check_authorization') [enabled by default]
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
.
make: *** [mod_wsgi.la] Error 1
```

From the error message it looks like it is trying to use python2.7 when I want 3.3, although I don't know that this is the cause of the error.
I think that would stem from `make`, as it says it checked for python in `/usr/bin/python` and not `/usr/bin/python3.3`.

How can I get this to work properly?

I am running apache2, django1.6, ubuntu 13.10

**EDIT**

I was able to get `./configure` to work by running `./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python3.3`, but now I get a different error:

```
~/sources/mod_wsgi-3.3$ make
/usr/bin/apxs2 -c -I/usr/include/python3.3m -DNDEBUG   mod_wsgi.c -L/usr/lib -    L/usr/lib/python3.3/config  -lpython3.3 -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm
/usr/share/apr-1.0/build/libtool --silent --mode=compile --tag=disable-static x86_64-    linux-gnu-gcc -std=gnu99 -prefer-pic -pipe -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4     -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-aliasing  -    D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE  -pthread  -I/usr/include/apache2  -    I/usr/include/apr-1.0   -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python3.3m -    DNDEBUG  -c -o mod_wsgi.lo mod_wsgi.c && touch mod_wsgi.slo
mod_wsgi.c:135:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Python.h"
                   ^
compilation terminated.
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
.
make: *** [mod_wsgi.la] Error 1
```

Comment: To fix that Python.h error, you'll need to install the python header files with `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of compiling mod_wsgi for python3.3 yourself, you could try to install [the ubuntu package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3)